# Nginx rewritten URL fails to redirect

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have been trying to redirect a specific URL of the type
`https://subdomain.example.com/story_meta_info.php?id=9483` to `https://subdomain.example.com/dash/#/story/9483`

I have tried using this rewrite rule but it keeps adding `?id=9483` at the end.

```
rewrite ^/story_meta_info\.php.* https://$host/dash/#/story/$arg_title redirect;
```

Am I doing something wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a replacement string includes the new request arguments, the previous request arguments are appended after them. If this is undesired, putting a question mark at the end of a replacement string avoids having them appended, for example:

```
rewrite ^/story_meta_info\.php.* https://$host/dash/#/story/$arg_id? redirect;
```

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Comment: This is working `rewrite ^/story_meta_info\.php.* https://$host/dash/#/story/$arg_id? redirect;`.

Comment: Could you change arg_title to arg_id and then I can accept this answer